# Can I set a contribution page to have pledge selected by default with a default number of installments?

Tags: civicontribute, pledges

I would like to have my contribution page default to pledge instead of one-time and also have a default number of installments. Is this possible?

[image: pledge selected by default]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't currently a setting to change this behavior. You will need to add JavaScript to your template file (or via an extension) to check if the donation page has pledge as an option, and if so, to select it.